# WebdriverIO trying to click on the a href element

Tags: html, testing, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver-io

I am trying to click on the "a href" using WebdriverIO.

```html
<a href="report.php?a=browse_titles" class="m_library">Library</a>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
browser.click('.m_library');
browser.click('[href="report.php?a=browse_titles"]');
browser.click('[class="m_library"]');
```

I tried more variations besides the ones I just mentioned above, but nothing works:( Any idea of how to click on the element with class name?
Also, when I try to use `isExisting` method with ".m_orders" and it returns true...

Comment: What happens when you run these? What error message(s) are you getting? Can you share the site?

Comment: I cant share the site, its internal for work. The error messages are always the same and like this `Error: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).`, or `Error: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.`

Comment: but when i use `isExisting` method - `var isExisting = browser.isExisting('.m_library');
            console.log(isExisting);
        console.log(browser.elements('.m_library'));` it finds the element

Comment: `․․․․․․true
{ sessionId: 'ba83c2f32f8cca695993e1e44a670985',
  value: 
   [ { ELEMENT: '0.3030587761802812-1',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.3030587761802812-1',
       selector: '.m_library',
       value: [Object],
       index: 0 } ],
  selector: '.m_library',
  _status: 0 }`

Comment: It would be more helpful if you put the error messages next to the locators that caused them in your question. An invalid selector should be fixable but we don't know which one to fix. Element not visible means you are retrieving either the wrong element or you might need to wait for it to become visible.

Comment: How do you wait for it to become visible?

Comment: I don't know for WebDriver-IO. In Java and C#, there is `WebDriverWait` which allows you to wait for an element to become visible. You should be able to google it and find something.

Answer (score 0):

The top and bottom tries don't match up with the class specified in the HTML you posted. Try

```
browser.click('a.m_library');
```

You could also try an XPath like

```
//a[.='Library']
```

Comment: Hi JeffC, oh yeah its just a typo here when I posted the question and i just  edited it, but I did try with a.m_library, and your XPath statement too! Its crazy, nothing works, I am totally lost and starting to think maybe it is some kind of bug in WebdriverIO

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with some of the possible implementations:

**Some usual ones**

```
browser.click('a.m_library');

browser.click('a[href="report.php?a=browse_titles"]');

browser.waitForVisible('a.m_library').click('=Library');
```

You can try more variations with xpath OR use [webdriverio API](http://webdriver.io/) to implement more.

**Try injecting JS like this:**

```
browser.execute(() => {
            $('a.m_library').trigger({ type: 'mousedown', which: 3 });
        });
```

**OR**

```
browser.execute(() => {
            $('a.m_library').click();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const links = $$('some-element a');  // Get all links within element
links.forEach(async (link) => {
  if (link.getAttribute('href').indexOf('full or partial link text here') !== -1) {  // e.g. all or part of your href link.  indexOf is IE compliant.
    link.click();
  }
});
```

or:

common.js:

```
  // Find all links <a> within a selector and click the link with matching href text
  function clickLink(selector, hrefText) {
    const links = $$(`${selector} a`);
    links.forEach(async (link) => {
      if (link.getAttribute('href').indexOf(hrefText) !== -1) {
        link.click();
      }
    });
  }

  module.exports = { clickLink };
```

---

test.js:

```
  const { clickLink } = require('common');
  ...
  // Look within element --some-element-- for all links <a> and click the one with the matching --href-text--
  clickLink('--some-element--', '--href-text--');
```

or simpler:

```
    const link = $('a[href*="href-text"]');
    link.click();
```